# Java - What would cause a while-loop to execute, even when false?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a rather large program I'm working on and I cannot figure out for the life of me why a while statement (inside a method) is executing, when the method itself works. I know the method itself is correct, but something within the rest of the program is making it execute.

So my question is, what should I look for in order to try to fix this?

Please keep in mind this is just a snippet of my entire program, and the following code works!

Here is the problem area of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoatTest
{
private double boatPrice;
private double downPayment;
private boolean boatIsNew;



//default constructor
public BoatTest()
{
boatPrice = 0.0;
downPayment = 0.0;
boatIsNew = false;
}//end method



//non-default constructor
public BoatTest(double boatPricePassed, double downPaymentPassed, 
boolean boatIsNewPassed)
{
setBoatPrice(boatPricePassed);
setDownPayment(downPaymentPassed);
setBoatIsNew(boatIsNewPassed); 
}//end method



//setters
public void setBoatPrice(double boatPricePassed)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
//test > 0
while(boatPricePassed < 0)
{
System.out.println("Invalid, must be >= 0. ");
System.out.println("Please enter the boat price:");
boatPricePassed = keyboard.nextDouble();
}//end while
boatPrice = boatPricePassed;
}//end method

public void setDownPayment(double downPaymentPassed)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
//test > 0
while(downPaymentPassed < 0)
{
System.out.println("Invalid, must be >= 0. ");
System.out.println("Please enter the down payment:");
downPaymentPassed = keyboard.nextDouble();
}//end while

//test if used > .30
while((downPaymentPassed < boatPrice * .30) && (boatIsNew == false))
{
System.out.println("Invalid, must be > " + (boatPrice * .30) + ".");
System.out.println("Please enter the down payment:");
downPaymentPassed = keyboard.nextDouble();
}//end while

downPayment = downPaymentPassed;
}//end method

public void setBoatIsNew(boolean boatIsNewPassed)
{
boatIsNew = boatIsNewPassed;
}//end method




//getters
public double getBoatPrice()
{
return boatPrice;
}//end method

public double getDownPayment()
{
return downPayment;
}//end method

public boolean getBoatIsNew()
{
return boatIsNew;
}//end method




//output
public String toString()
{
return
"\nBoat Price: " + boatPrice +
"\nDown Payment: " + downPayment +
"\nBoat Is New: " + boatIsNew;
}//end method



}//end class
```

And here is the main method:

```
public class BoatTestMain
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

System.out.println("Create first instance of Boat class");
BoatTest b1 = new BoatTest (29900, 9900, false);
System.out.println("Create second instance of Boat class");
BoatTest b2 = new BoatTest (10000, 0, false);

System.out.println("The first boat information:");
System.out.println(b1.toString());
System.out.println("The second boat information:");
System.out.println(b2.toString());


}//end main
}//end class
```

In setDownPayment, specifically:

```
while((downPaymentPassed < boatPrice * .30) && (boatIsNew == false))
{
System.out.println("Invalid, must be > " + (boatPrice * .30) + ".");
System.out.println("Please enter the down payment:");
downPaymentPassed = keyboard.nextDouble();
}//end while
```

My entire program has the exact same values within the main method. However, rather than only asking for a new down payment on boat 2, it asks it for boat 1 as well, giving me the message...

```
Problem:
Invalid, must be > 3000.0.
Please enter the down payment:
```

I've been looking through my program for hours now and can't figure it out for the life of me. If any of you guys could give any insight on the issue it would be much appreciated.

I can post the entire code if anyone wants to take a look at it, but it's long and confusing.

Comment: Consider a validation method which handles the loop in isolation.  The only real differences between those loops is what gets validated and when.  This way, you can more narrowly identify what the actual issue is.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Which while loop is "executing even when false"?

Comment: There are many while loops, which one has the problem?

Comment: @Munyari setDownPayment method

Comment: He wants to know which while loop in the method is being called while false...

Comment: I edited my question to highlight the problem area more. Thanks for your time guys, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Also a note, you say your code is long and confusing, maybe that should raise a problem of what IF someone wanted to read your code? It shouldn't be longer than it needs to, and with proper documentation shouldn't be confusing.

Comment: @liquidsystem To me it looks confusing I don't know if that would be true for everyone, and it's meant to be long because its a project for school with lots of variables and excessive uses of intro Java stuff. In other words, its to help us learn, and practice, and we need to do it a specific way or its considered "incorrect" by the professor.

Comment: @Makoto is there any way you could elaborate for me on how to exactly do that?

Comment: 30% of 10000 is 3000.  0 < 3000 so your loop will correctly engage.  Did you mean to enter a 0 in as your second bit of data?

Comment: @Makoto Yes I'm sorry I should have also explained that part more. Everything that executes within the code I posted works as it should. The problem is, when I load up the entire code and not just that snippet, the while-loop is being executed for boat 1 as well.

Comment: Unless your fields are declared as static, I can't envision that scenario happening.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to only include the relevant code. Not everyone has the time or patience to read/parse through all that code to find what _might_ be the problematic part.

Comment: I still don't understand why its confusing to YOU, the creator of the program, if you consider it confusing would it be something you want released? I'm not knocking your skills just questioning why you're making a program that is confusing to you as the developer.

Comment: @Arc676 the code I posted is merely just reference, my question is what can I do/look for within my entire code in order to fix a while-loop from executing even when false.

Comment: @liquidsystem I would say its confusing because the concepts of methods, getters, setters, constructors is still somewhat new to me, and the fact its such a large set of variables and methods required. It just looks like a mess of code to me, but I can still understand it with time :)

Comment: Please indent your code nicely. Then you won't have to name your end-block-brackets by comments. Reduce the code to the bare minimum and make it autonomously runnable, when compiled. Most of the time you will find the error in this process yourself.

Comment: You should only post the problematic loop then. For example, it's not important that we see your constructors, your class declaration, etc. We only need to see the setDownPayment method because that's where the problem is, isn't it? See how to write a [mcve] for more details.

Comment: A method called `setDownPayment()` should set the down-payment value, and possibly validate it. It should *not* print error messages to the user and solicit further input from him. That's part of the user interface. Clean up your code so its structure makes some sort of sense. Then your problem will probably magically disappear.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not going to find the bug in your code for you.  Debugging your own code is something you are supposed to be learning.

To answer your question:

> What would cause a while-loop to execute, even when false?

Nothing would!

The loop condition is in some sense<sup>1</sup> true.  You might not think so, and / you might not understand why, but it >>is<< true.

So what should you do?  Well in a situation like this where an application is behaving in a way that makes no sense (to you), the first thing to do is to use a debugger.

1. Start the debugger.
2. Set a breakpoint on the `while` statement.
3. Start the program running.
4. When it hits the breakpoint, use the debugger to examine the variables.  In this case `downPaymentPassed`, `boatPrice` and `boatIsNew`.
5. Work out what the condition *should* evaluate to.

I predict that you will find that one or more of the variables does not have the value that you think it should have ... at that point.

One possibility that should be considered is that `downPaymentPassed < boatPrice * .30` gives an unexpected answer because of rounding error.  Floating point arithmetic and floating point literals (like `.30`) are not exact.  (I'm NOT saying that that IS the problem here, but it might be ... depending on what values the variables contain.)

---

<sup>1 - I'm be slightly cagey here.  It is theoretically possible that 1) you have a hardware fault, 2) there is a compiler bug, 3) your computer keeps on getting zapped by cosmic rays.  It another possible explanation (in a multithreaded application) is that the apparently inexplicable result is due to a concurrency bug; e.g. non-synchronized access to share variables.  However, you should discount these possibilities here.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code and it runs fine for me.

Such errors occur when you edit the code but forget to save it before compiling, or edit and compile, but save under new name or location and run the old code.

```
Create first instance of Boat class
Create second instance of Boat class
Invalid, must be > 3000.0.
Please enter the down payment:
4000
The first boat information:

Boat Price: 29900.0
Down Payment: 9900.0
Boat Is New: false
The second boat information:

Boat Price: 10000.0
Down Payment: 4000.0
Boat Is New: false
```